# How to use set function with numpy array string?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set

I want to do this in my numpy array of strings

```
>>> set('Hello world')
{' ', 'H', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'w'}
```

This is what I have done

```
>>> x=np.array([[' X-ray is dangerous'],['Zebra crosses the road'],['I Love XYZ']])

>>>set(x.flatten())
{' X-ray is dangerous', 'I Love XYZ', 'Zebra crosses the road'}

>>> np.unique(x)
array([' X-ray is dangerous', 'I Love XYZ', 'Zebra crosses the road'], 
  dtype='|S22')
```

See its not giving the desired output and I want to get the set values of whole numpy array and not just for the rows. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "not just the rows"?  Your array is 1-dimensional, so it has no rows.  Are you saying you want the set to contain the individual characters of the strings in the array?

Comment: @BrenBarn sorry for that I have edited the question

Comment: If your question has been answered, would you please mark the checkmark beside the correct answer? It helps future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> set("".join(x.flatten()))
{'r', ' ', 'g', 'y', 'h', 'I', 'd', '-', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'Z', 's', 'o', 't', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'e', 'Y', 'X', 'u', 'L'}
```

Or if you're concerned about very large `numpy` arrays:

```
>>> data = set()
>>> for row in x.flatten():
...     data.update(row)
...
>>> 
# {'r', ' ', 'g', 'y', 'h', 'I', 'd', '-', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'Z', 's', 'o', 't', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'e', 'Y', 'X', 'u', 'L'}
```

Comment: I have edited the question with multiple rows and it doesn't work in it

Comment: Updated to handle your new scenario. You'd already found `x.flatten()`; it's exactly what you'd need here.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply and I have accepted your answer :)

Comment: No problem. Good luck, Eka!